# Allowing only certain IP Addresses

Tags: windows-7, firewall

How would I allow only certain IP addresses to connect to me for Xbox Live? I did block all inbound rules and then added a custom rule to allow only certain IPs to connect to me, but some other people can still connect to me.

Answer (score 1):

XBox Live uses a uPnP request from the XBox console to the router, then going through that connection to the xboxlive server.

I don't know exactly how it connects (hmm, new experiment!), but I'd imagine people's IP's are passed back and forth from the xboxlive connection, which the console then uses for another uPnP request (to the router) to make that connection.

It's kind of an all or nothing thing.  You can block people in your profile, and actually set it to 'friends only', which would prevent random people from bothering you.

Comment: Well, like I mean in a game. I want only some people to connect to me in multiplayer games like Saints Row.

Comment: @lornix I think the OPs intentions are a bit more devious. Back in the Halo 2 era person "A" would block everything but the XBL server IP and the IP of person "B".  XBL would then force host to the console of person "B" because that was the only console person "A" could connect to.  I expect this is what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: Yes. You got it. That is EXACTLY what I am trying to do. For Saints Row Pimp Killer.

Comment: I imagine you should still be able to limit to everyone, friends, or no-one.  Of course, I don't have that game (yet), so I'm just guessing based on my other games behaviour.   Usually it's in the 'profile settings' pane of the main console menus (settings)

Comment: No, that cannot be done. :( It is a "ranked" game, so it by passes all that. Which is why I am further trying to bypass it.

Comment: Hmm, bummer.  Good luck then.  Please be sure to post an answer if you do figure out how, without the game, I'm limited. {Grin}